# Should a Rabbi apologize for a comment that could be misunderstood?

Tags: halacha, words, rabbis, repentance-teshuvah, marit-ayin

If a prominent Rabbi (meaning someone who heads a community or institution, not just anyone who has semicha) makes a statement that is technically halachically correct/acceptable but is easily misconstrued or misunderstood. If that comment becomes public knowledge, meaning it is posted online and seized upon by the media in a way that brings shame to either the Rabbi, his affiliated organization or Judaism as a whole; should the Rabbi apologize? Please cite sources either from chazal or written halachic rulings.

I am assuming

1. What was said does not violate halacha in any way
2. The thing that was said was done so not expecting that it would be exposed to the greater world

Comment: What does his being a Rabbi have to do with it? Shouldn't anyone who makes a mistake apologize, particularly if it ended up being harmful to others?

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume it is different because if the comment is picked up by the mainstream media the fact that it is a Rabbi would carry different weight and might be the only reason the media picks up on it at all - "regular person says something appaling" doesn't have the same ring to it

Comment: Right, so if his action caused more harm by his stature, even if unintentional, how much more so would an apology be necessary, and it would create a huge Kiddush haShem! If I see the rabbi in question apologize for his mistake, how much more so will I realize I should apologize for any of mine.

Comment: You're asking specifically about apologizing, but would this question work better if it asked "what steps should he take?".  I mean, it sounds like apologizing, while relevant, isn't his top priority -- correcting the mistaken impression would be, no?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I am assuming apologizing would be the way to correct the mistaken impression (ie not just saying I am sorry, but explaining yourself as part of the apology). Since the speaker did nothing halachically wrong I assume he has nothing else to do, hence I don't understand the teshuva tag which was added.

Comment: @nikmasi If I cause someone harm unintentionally, wouldn't that at least be a sin beshogeg? Hence teshuva.

Comment: @DoubleAA the converse is that it can be seen as an insult to torah and the honor of a talmud chacham. In the case of Rav Schachter, his choosing not to apologize would seem to indicate his psak on the matter.

Comment: @nikmasi What?? Adderabba! Saying such things in public is the biggest insult to Torah and the honor of Talmidei Chachamim, and a Chillul haShem as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA depends on your definition of harm. As I said, in my hypothetical example no halacha was broken so no damage, monetary or otherwise should have occurred.

Comment: @nikmasi You said it brings shame to the affiliated organization or Judaism as a whole. That is damage.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know about that. There are many things that Jews do which the would looks down upon them for but we don't apologize for. I give my kid a bris milah no matter how heathenistic the world may esteem it to be.

Comment: @nikmasi Did you just compare fulfilling a mitzva deoraita (with kareis) to insulting whole swaths of people for no reason?

Comment: @DoubleAA I hope I didn't do that. I was comparing fulfilling a deoraita with kavod ha'torah and kavod of prominent rabbis. I know there is an urge to contextualize this to current events, but I am eschewing that because I want to see a general answer as I'm sure this type of situation has come about previously. Also, no upvote, even for my witty repartee?

Comment: "Should he apologize" seems, actually, very vague, since "apologies" can take all kinds of forms that have very different meanings and effects. So, what you're really asking is "should he make a statement, and what should it be?" It seems to me that this is a question of PR judgement much more than of Halacha or even Mussar, and that it's very unlikely that there would be sources that would both address this question and be applicable to other cases.

Comment: @IsaacMoses there are many discussions of proper behavior for a talmud chacham, such as not taking long steps or walking with patched sandals etc. which are not germane to halacha necessarily. I don't see why this wouldn't fall under that category. And regarding to it being discussed in the literature, well unfortunately it seems to be a common enough occurrence that I would be surprised if it was **not** discussed. I don't think this has anything to do with PR, and everything to do with what is the proper response of a prominent torah personality in this type of situation

Comment: @nikmasi, You're asking what a public figure should say to the public to manage certain feelings within the public. That's PR. It happens to be that a) the public official is a prominent Torah personality, and b) mixed in here, there's the possibility of the PR making some implication about Halacha. (a) doesn't change the fact that what's requested is a PR strategy, and what would be appropriate and effective is *very* dependent on the situation. (b) adds in an important, on-topic consideration that is nonetheless just as situation-dependent.

Comment: Am I the only one who has no idea what sort of comment this was?

Comment: @SAH, this question is (properly, IMO) addressing a hypothetical situation in general rather than a particular episode in current events. (Though I'm still not convinced that it's answerable.)

Comment: "If that comment becomes public knowledge, meaning it is posted online and seized upon by the media in a way that brings shame to either the Rabbi, his affiliated organization or Judaism as a whole; should the Rabbi apologize?" Why would he apologize if it causes shame to himself? Perhaps you mean only "that brings shame to either the Rabbi's organization or Judaism as a whole"?

Comment: @DoubleAA re your first comment, "Shouldn't anyone who makes a mistake apologize, particularly if it ended up being harmful to others?", the question says the rabbi spoke *correctly* and was merely misunderstood. Seems to me it's the media who harmed others. I know _hizaharu b'divrechem_ (I'm probably misquoting that, from _Avos_) but that doesn't mean it's obvious the rabbi should apologize!

Comment: @msh210 I don't understand your point. I said it was accidental. Mistakes generally are. That doesn't mean you don't apologize for something _beshogeg_. Additionally, perhaps your not appreciating the extent to which public figures ought to go to maintain "PR" as Isaac put it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I was commenting only on your first comment's seeming incredulity at the question of whether an apology is in order: you seemed to be taken it as obvious that the answer is yes. I was saying that it's not so obvious (though of course the answer may be "yes" anyway).

Comment: @msh210 I maintain it is obvious if someone/thing/entity is harmed/defamed/insulted etc. even accidentally.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think you need to step back and think about this in the abstract, the way it was asked.  Not every situation where someone is offended has there been an actual offense nor are things we don't necessarily wish to publicize things we should inherently be apologetic about. It's a legitimate question, if you would like to answer please do so, but otherwise please move on.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu It's not about the content. It's about the presentation. You can be unapologetic about the content while choosing a poor way of presenting. If that poor choice harms (etc.) something (etc.) then it is for sure apology worthy. And as others have noted above, it is not at all clear if this a legitimate question for this forum, let alone for any in its most abstract version.

Comment: @nikmasi You did make that comparison. You said: we don't apologize for bris milah which they think is bad, so too maybe we shouldn't apologize for insulting lots of people for no reason.

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified. Right now its wording includes the case that a prominent rabbi says to his friend while walking down the street "It is inappropriate for Jewish men to wear women's clothes in general" (paraphrasing a _pasuk_ in _Chumash_) and a reporter, overhearing it, publishes an article with the headline "Jews misogynistic". If the question means to include that case, fine; otherwise, it should clarify what it's asking about. Also ping @DoubleAA.

Comment: @msh210 I see no reason your example would not be included. I'm not sure how better to clarify and maintain this question in the abstract

Answer (score 3):

From pirkei Avos perek 1:11 we see that Avtaylon warned not to say something which can be misconstrued .one should be as clear as possible.

One can also see from the gemara in Yoma 86a that the Rabbanim would be careful with their actions so one should not learn and misinterpret their actions(see case with Rav and Abaye) and cause the greatest sin of chillul Hashem.

On the same daf Yitzchak davei Rabbi Yannai said that anyone whose friends are embarrassed on account of his bad reputation (even if untrue)  is a case of chillul Hashem .

It seems quite clear one has an obligation and responsibility to correct a false idea.

Comment: See the gemarah in Yoma for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I read a story of Rav Shach who gave a childless couple a bracha that they should have kids.

soem time later they had twins. Rav Shach came to be the bris.

At the bris the father asked him to be the sandek. He asked who would be the second sandek. the father replied something about the grandfather. Rav Shach then said that either he will be the sandek for both or not at all.

After a few minutes the word spread and some one there started spreading a rumor that Rav Shach is such an arrogant person for demanding to be the sandek for both kids or not at all.

When Rav Shach heard this, he announced to everyone that the reason he had done this is so that when the two babies grow up there should not be jealousy between them that one of them had a big rosh yeshiva as sandek.

Comment: Good story. Did he apologize?

Comment: who? rav shach?

Comment: Yes, because that's what the question is about. Without that information it's irrelevant.

Comment: apologize for what? he did nothing wrong. the question is confusing - it starts saying "makes a statement that is technically halachically correct/acceptable but is easily misconstrued or misunderstood" which implies he did nothing wrong. then it goes on to say "should he apologize?". no apology is needed. he should only clarify what he said. And this is what this story demonstrates.

Comment: I think you have the question exactly correct. Your answer gives a perfect example of such a case. But you don't tell the reader if he apologized or not. I'm not saying R' Shach should have apologized. I'm saying your answer is irrelevant without that information.

Comment: well then obviously he did not apologize (otherwise that would have been added to the story since it is noteworthy) but he did correct the misconveived perception. I think is the answer to this question - not to apologize but to correct/clarify the intentions.

Comment: If it were obvious, you'd probably have a few upvotes, no? I did not down vote, because I had a pretty good idea what you meant, but it's not in the answer, so I did not feel I could upvote. I'm offering you constructive criticism here to help you improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maaseh Rav - Rabbi Feldman made comments about Dov Lipman based on his understanding of what Dov had said. These comments were seized upon by the Jewish media, many of which decried the Chareidi leader's stance. When he later discovered that he had his facts wrong [he apologized](http://www.jpost.com/National-News/Rabbi-apologies-for-calling-MK-Lipman-wicked-312962). As to whether or not the comments violated halacha see [this post](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2013/05/calling-another-jew-rasha-evil.html)

I assume both his initial comments and later apology were intended to be made public.

Comment: I don't think this falls under the category of apologizing for comments that could be misunderstood. His words and intent were understood correctly. _He_ had been misinformed and spoke about what _he had been led to believe_ were someone else's words and intent. His apology, such that it was, was not because his words were misconstrued, but because he had been misinformed.